# Why does my Google Image search scrape time-out?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to download the first 10 images from a Google Image search of apples. I open Google Image search, search for apples and open the first image so it is full resolution. However, when I save it I always time out:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time
import urllib


firefox_binary_path = 'Credentials/geckodriver.exe'
firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.binary_location = firefox_binary_path
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/imghp')
search_box = driver.find_element("name", "q")
search_box.send_keys('Apples')
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
downloaded_count = 0
try:
    while downloaded_count < 10:
        search_results = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.rg_i')
        if downloaded_count < len(search_results):
            image = search_results[downloaded_count]
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(image).click(image).perform()
            img_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.iPVvYb')
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(img_locator))
            img = driver.find_element(*img_locator)
            img_url = img.get_attribute('src')
            resource = urllib.urlopen(img_url)
            filename = img_url.split('/')[-1] + '.jpg'
            output = open(filename, 'wb')
            output.write(resource.read())
            output.close()
            downloaded_count += 1
        else:
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(2)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Are you sure you need selenium for google search? There are free search json API available with and several python libs, there is a simple json structure returned.

Comment: The basic is - requests, httpx, aiohttp etc. You can reverse engineer API, using `Network` tab in dev console (for chromium browsers its F12), or, just google docs for it, I'm sure, community already researched it. And also, ironically, there is a lib called `Google-Images-Search` in py-pi, I'm sure, you can find more libs like this if it doesn't work like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you need Selenium for this, however, if you want to use Selenium for downloading images, you can use combination of Selenium + `requests` library and use it's `get` method.

This library is HTTP Client that can help you to get response content from the resource.

```py
import requests

# your code until getting image from for loop

       img = driver.find_element(*img_locator)
       img_url = img.get_attribute('src')
       response = requests.get(img_url)
       filename = img_url.split('/')[-1] + '.jpg'
       output = open(filename, 'wb')
       output.write(response.content)
       output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The filename requires sanitising for characters such as `,`, `.` and `&`. For example `apples-700x350-edfec3b.png?quality=90&resize=556,505.jpg`. These can be removed using `.replace()` method on the string before using it to create a file.

Using Selenium for this isn't ideal.